# Azure DevOps Server

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2020

I'm facing an issue in our On-Premise Azure DevOps Server 2020 where, in any TSR, I cannot find my organization's AD users in the `Requested By` combo-box for me to select:

[image: No users found]

Is this linked to AD users or some property in templates?

Answer (score 0):

because AD users might be many , identity fields like RequestedBy show users after search him by name or username(in AD)